# Extracting sound spectrum data in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, xna

I was very dissatisfied when I realized that the MediaLibrary's GetVisualizationData() returns a bunch of zeros on WP7. What are the other approaches I could apply in order to compute and extract sound spectrum data from my MediaLibrary's song collection ?

P.S. The way it's written suggests that I'm working on an XNA project. I would be glad to accept even Silverlight-related approaches, as this is more of a general problem I'm struggling with

Comment: i believe they're all written regarding XNA as all of the sound libraries are part of XNA, since silverlight is more of an "application" framework.  There are only a few xna things that you *cannot* use in a silverlight app, the sound/media stuff is all ok to use from silverlight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to write your own algorithm. It's not exactly easy, but what you're looking for is [Beat Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_detection) (this page has some links to get you started).

**EDIT:**
Here is some [Java source-code](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/analysis/BeatDetect.java) for beat detection from the [Mimim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) library.

Comment: @user252160: See updated link to Java source - this can likely easily be ported to XNA or SL3 for use with WP7.

Comment: Has anyone converted this to C# yet?

Answer (score 5):

Per the documentation (as of the writing of this post):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.isvisualizationenabled.aspx

> "Visualization data is not available
>   on Windows Phone. Any attempt to get
>   visualization data on the phone will
>   populate the VisualizationData class
>   with 0s."

If this is a feature you'd like to see supported on windows phone, you should go to the [Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com) and submit an issue. These issues are tracked, and especially if you're able to get community support behind it and get people to vote on it, perhaps it will be implemented in a future release :-)

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I don't think that they are going to introduce it soon. If there's another approach, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: For the time being, there is no other approach on the WP7 platform. Until they announce new API features, your best bet is to submit/vote on a connect item for this :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think that I have found exactly what you are looking for.  [Beat Detection](http://www.enchantedage.com/fft-in-xna-content-pipeline-for-beat-detection-for-the-win) written by JWatte.  From the screenshot, its looking very pretty.

[Here](http://cespage.com/silverlight/wp7tut20.html) is a little framework, in Silverlight, that might assist with your project.

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/FFT-and-oscilloscopes-in-Silverlight) is a Silverlight FFT and oscilloscopes example.

Comment: I find it interesting that this answer got four upvotes, while [Otaku's identical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527013/extracting-sound-spectrum-data-in-wp7/5121209#5121209) (posted ***two days earlier***) got only one upvote (as of this writing).

Comment: @Robert: My Beat Detection link is a link to an actual example.  Not to Wikipedia like Otaku's.

Comment: It uses a low level library written in C. I know that running unmanaged code is at least technically possible in WP7, but not officially supported.