# Displaying a sound visualizer using silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to display a sound visualizer in my little app, which displays the loudness got from the value stream from the microphone.

An example is here:
http://randomfractals.com/blog/2010/03/26/spark-path-sound-visualizer/

I know the idea of doing such a visualizer, e.g. setting up a circular array to hold, say 100, recent loudness and display the array into a histogram chart. The chart is just a 100 (width) by 300 (height) "big pixel" space. Each big pixel is actually 3 pixel by 3 pixel. By filling white and black to the "big pixels", I get my real-time sound visualizer.

My question is that in silver light, what kind of control allows me to do such things? A control allows me to draw things on it is enough for me:)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This question and its answers might be of some use to you

[Extracting sound spectrum data in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527013/extracting-sound-spectrum-data-in-wp7)

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight Toolkit chart controls can be use on WP7 with some tweaking as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx). There are also control vendors such as [Visifire](http://visifire.com) and [Mindscape](http://www.mindscapehq.com/) that offer charting controls for WP7. One of these should be adequate for your requirements.

**UDPATE:** Another one I forgot was [amCharts Quick Charts for WPF, Silverlight, and WP7](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick), which is free and open source.

Comment: Also note that Visiblox (http://www.visiblox.com) is also an option with their free component (see an example that's somewhat similar here: http://www.visiblox.com/examples/RealTimeUpdates