# Accessing the output audio buffer on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

The MediaPlayer.GetVisualizationData method does not work for Windows Phone 7, so I'm trying to find another way to visualize music playing through the MediaPlayer.

The post [Extracting sound spectrum data in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527013/extracting-sound-spectrum-data-in-wp7) gives a method for doing beat detection given an audio buffer, but it doesn't explain how to get this buffer on the phone.

How can I access audio samples/frequency data from the music MediaPlayer is playing? I'm not trying to access a buffer from the microphone - I need access to the output audio on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to this other SO question:
[Extracting sound spectrum data in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527013/extracting-sound-spectrum-data-in-wp7/4529149#4529149)

> "Visualization data is not available
>   on Windows Phone. Any attempt to get
>   visualization data on the phone will
>   populate the VisualizationData class
>   with 0s."